# Looking for efficient way of splitting array into k-arrays

Tags: java, arrays, partitioning

I am trying to create a program that takes an integer array in increasing order and split it into k non-empty arrays in increasing order which when combined into a single array produce the original array - the first array cannot contain any but the first or more digits (k1=[1,2,3] is valid but k1=[2,3,4] is not)

So far I have tried given a `array[4,7,11,21,31]` and `k=3` hard-coding two for-loops that act as pointers on where to copy the items and copying part of the original array into the respected variables

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
     int k = 3;
     int n = 5; 
     for(int i = 0; i <= n - k; i++){
       for(int j = i+1; j < n-1; j++){
         int[] k1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array , 0, i+1);
         int[] k2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array , i+1, j+1);
         int[] k3 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array , j+1, n);
       }
     }
```

The above code works for `k=3` but the problem is that I do not know how to efficiently make it work for any `k` and efficiently store the arrays

The end goal is to generate all possible combinations

Comment: So you want to have all possible combinations of k non-empty arrays that produce the original array when concatenated?

Comment: @TheBlackIPs Yes, that is correct. For example k1=[1,2] k2=[3,4] k3=[5]. k1 cannot contain any digit that is not the first or the first and the following. Also it is not required to be arrays. That is what I used for my initial try.

Comment: If we're talking efficiency, would it be enough to just have the indices where each of the splits are? (`i+1` and `j+1` in this example)

Comment: @TheBlackIPs Well not entirely sure. I am looking for efficiency of less than O(n * n * n * k) where n is the size of the original array

Comment: Yeah, but what is the task at hand? What are the requirements? You said it is not required to be arrays, what could the result be then?

Comment: @TheBlackIPs I just need those k-containers to be store in memory so it can be Lists, arrays, anything. The end result is to print those in the format "k1, k2, k3 etc."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192170/discussion-between-jon-doe-and-theblackips).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This recursive brute-force approach doesn't really split an array of numbers, it just returns the indices of the array entries where the splits have to happen.

It takes two arguments:

- `n` the length of the array
- `k` the number of parts wanted

It will return an `ArrayList<int[]>` that contains all possible combinations of splits (each of those as an array of indices with `k-1` elements in ascending order).

I have tried some cases and it seems to work. As expected, it always seems to return the binomial coefficient `(n-1) over (k-1)` amount of combinations. This is because in any array with length `n` there are `n-1` places where it could be split into two. We only want to split it `k-1` times, though (to end up with `k` parts). So this is basically selecting `k-1` from `n-1`, thus the binomial coefficient.

```
public static ArrayList<int[]> getSplits(int n, int k) {
    if (k == 1) {
        return new ArrayList<int[]>();
    }

    ArrayList<int[]> newSplits = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    for (int s = 1; s < n-(k-1)+1; s++) {
        if (k == 2) {
            newSplits.add(new int[] {s});
        } else {
            ArrayList<int[]> splits = getSplits(n-s, k-1);

            for (int[] split : splits) {
                int[] newSplit = new int[split.length + 1];
                newSplit[0] = s;
                for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                    newSplit[i+1] = split[i] + s;
                }
                newSplits.add(newSplit);
            }
        }
    }
    return newSplits;
}
```

**Used in the context of your question:**

To get your array parts from this, you can use this function. It outputs them separated by pipe symbols (`|`).

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int n = array.length;
    int k = 3;

    ArrayList<int[]> splits = getSplits(n, k);

    for (int[] split : splits) {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            for (; j < split[i]; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("| ");
        }
        for (; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This prints the following (all possibilites to split 4 items into 3 non-empty groups):

```
1 | 2 | 3 4 
1 | 2 3 | 4 
1 2 | 3 | 4
```